# Evaluate limit without evaluating integral

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

Is it possible to evaluate the limit
$$
  \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to + 0} \epsilon^2\int\limits_0^\epsilon \frac{r^{d-1} \, dr}{(r^2+\epsilon^2)^{\frac{d+2}{2}}}, \quad d > 2,
$$
without evaluating the integral for each $\epsilon > 0$? Estimating the numerator in the integral by $r(r^2+\epsilon^2)^{\frac{d-2}{2}}$ I can obtain an upper estimate $1/4$. The L'Hopital rule doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to + 0} \epsilon^2\int\limits_0^\epsilon \frac{r^{d-1} \, dr}{(r^2+\epsilon^2)^{\frac{d+2}{2}}} =\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to + 0}  \int\limits_0^1 \frac{u^{d-1} \, du}{(u^2+1)^{\frac{d+2}{2}}}.$$
Then, clearly, we need to evaluate the last expression, which is not that evident.